# Webpage sometimes cannot connect to other url with SSL

Tags: c#, ssl, webclient

We have an application (WebAPI, let's name it "X") working on IIS on Windows Server 2012 R2. Sometimes "X" cannot connect to other independent API's on the web. We got error:

> The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust
>   relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
>
> The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation
>   procedure.

I've done some testing and at the same time "X" cannot download https://google.com (using `WebClient` class) but I can browse it with web browser on that current server.

Also I tried to ignore server certificate errors for whole application (code below) but it didn't help too.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{    
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
        (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
}
```

My clients have no problem connecting to "X". Also when the error occures on one server I am able to successfully connect (https://google.com for example) on other servers with different instance of "X".

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your IIS web application is running under a user context that doesn't have access to the certificates on the machine.  However, the browser is running under a different user context that does have access. That explains your test results.

If the user does have access to the certificates, then possibly you will need to download the certificates from the independent API's.  See this: http://brainof-dave.blogspot.com.au/2008/08/remote-certificate-is-invalid-according.html

Check out these resources too:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saurabh_singh/2009/07/02/required-permissions-when-calling-a-web-service-using-client-certificate-for-authentication-in-an-asp-net-web-application/

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772237(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks Donald but does it mean that I have to add certificate manually for each API we use on every server running instance of our application?
Also I think I'm unable to get certificate file for http://google.com or https://graph.windows.net